# Proper reinitialization of a list? What is happening under the hood?

Tags: list, quote, mutability

I'm teaching myself some more elisp and have encountered the following problem:

If I want to reset a list variable it won't get updated after the first evaluation. Here is some example code:

```el
(defun initilize ()
  (setq example '(3)))

(defun modify ()
  (initilize)
  (message "%S" example)
  (setcar example 2))

; M-x eval-buffer RET
(modify) ; message --> (3)
(modify) ; message --> (2)
(modify) ; message --> (2)
```

I'm interested in two things. The first is to learn more about what is happening "under the hood" so why does it work the first time and fails on subsequent calls?

The second and more practical question is how to reinitialize the list properly or is there another common way of doing something like that?

One workaround I found myself is to use a quoted list and evaluating 
the content like this:

```
(setq example `(,3))
```

Comment: Summary: Do not expect `'(some list)` to be `eq` to `'(some list)` - *ever*.There is generally no guarantee in Lisp that code that visibly quotes a list returns new list structure each time. In some Lisp implementations it might, or it might some of the time. In others, it never does. Your code should anyway not depend on any such behavior from the implementation. **If you want new list structure, use `list` or `cons` or equivalent.**

Comment: (I'm guessing that this question is a duplicate, but I don't know where the duplicate is.)

Comment: I think that the problem here is that `example` has never been declared as a variable, so `setq` must be acting as if it declares a new variable, but later on when you call `initialize` again a new variable is being created, while `modify` remembers the old one... in any case this is not an expected behavior, however, the use of `setq` with something that hasn't been introduced earlier as a variable might as well be undefined.

Comment: @wvxvw It happens when you declare `example` with defvar, too.

Comment: OK, I figured out what happens. `'(3)` is treated as a literal value, so once you `(setcar '(3) 2)`, whenever you do `(defvar foo '(3))` or `(let ((foo '(3)))` and so on you will likely get a value of `foo` equal to `'(2)`. I say "likely" because this behavior isn't guaranteed, it's a kind of optimization that the interpreter does whenever it feels like, something known as constants subexpression elimination (a particular case of). So, what **abo-abo** wrote is not exactly the reason. It's more like modifying a string literal in C (which typically generates a warning).

Comment: I knew this is the case in Common Lisp, but never thought that Emacs Lisp also does this.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/16670989

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this will clear up some of the confusion:

- Your function `initilize` does not initialize variable `example`.  It sets it to a particular cons cell - the same cons cell each time it is called. The first time `initilize` is called, the `setq` assigns `example` to a new cons cell, which is the result of evaluating `'(3)`. Subsequent calls to `initilize` just reassign `example` to the same cons cell.
- Since `initilize` just reassigns the same cons cell to `example`, `modify` just sets the car of that same cons cell to `2` each time it is called.
- To initialize a list, use `list` or `cons` (or an equivalent backquote sexp, such as `` `(,(+ 2 1)) `` or `` `(,3) ``). For example, use **`(list 3)`**.

The key to understanding this is to know that a quoted cons cell is evaluated only once, and thereafter the same cons cell is returned.  This is not necessarily the way that all Lisps behave, but it is how Emacs Lisp behaves.

More generally, the behavior of evaluating a quoted mutable object is implementation dependent, if not language dependent.  In Common Lisp, for example, I'm pretty sure that there is nothing in the definition (spec) of the language that defines the behavior in this regard - it is left up to the implementation.

**Summary:** Do not expect '(some list) to be eq to '(some list) - ever.There is generally *no guarantee* in Lisp that code that visibly quotes a list returns new list structure each time.  In some Lisp implementations it might, or it might some of the time.  In others, it never does.  Your code should anyway not depend on any such behavior from the implementation.  If you want new list structure, use `list` or `cons` or equivalent.

Comment: Is the condescending tone in the two first lines of your answer necessary? Otherwise an enlightening answer.

Comment: @asjo: The intention wasn't to condescend in any way; sorry. Hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: Thanks to clear things up a bit. With the term "argument" I meant the argument `(,3) for the setq function, although I understand it is a bit unclear because I'm really evaluating the 3 in the quoted list. I will edit that.

Comment: @Drew Great! It's friendlier to read now.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `(setq example (list 3))` to avoid this error.

What happens is `init` assigns an object that initially contains `(3)` to `example`.
It sets the value of the object only once. Subsequently, you modify this value.

Here's your example in C++, if you understand that better:

```c++
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char* example;
char* storage = 0;
char* create_object_once (const char* str) {
  if (storage == 0) {
    storage = new char[strlen (str)];
    strcpy (storage, str);
  }
  return storage;
}
void init () {
  example = create_object_once ("test");
}
void modify () {
  init ();
  printf ("%s\n", example);
  example[0] = 'f';
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  modify ();
  modify ();
  modify ();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know C++ but I understand your example. One thing still bothers me though: In your code example you introduce the variable storage which creates the object with the initial value only if it was not set yet. How does that translate to what the Emacs Lisp Interpreter is doing? I mean if I reevaluate the `initilize` function and call `modify` again it will show `(3)` again only because I reevaluated the function.

Comment: I can't get into specifics (don't exactly know them), but think of `(3)` as a temporary object that's part of `init`. `init`'s body sets `example` to the address of that temporary object, it doesn't touch its value.