# Why is this function not pure

Tags: list, quote, mutability

I just spent a significant amount of time debugging an issue that boils down to the following:

```
(defun my-new-alist ()
  `((x . nil)))

(setq a (my-new-alist))
(setq b (my-new-alist))

(push 1 (alist-get 'x a))
b ;; ((x . 1))
```

I expected `a` and `b` to be independent of each other (that is, I expected `my-new-alist` to be pure. Instead, it seems to create a new list when the defun is executed, and always return a reference to that very list. Part of my confusion stems from comparing with the following:

```
(defun my-new-list ()
  nil)

(setq a (my-new-list))
(setq b (my-new-list))

(push 1 a)
a ;; => (1)
b ;; => nil
```

Note also that anti-quoting the nil part fixes the issue, it seems; that is, the following function doesn't exhibit the problem:

```
(defun my-new-alist ()
  `((x . ,nil)))
```

What is the significant difference between the list and alist examples? Which parts of the ELisp manual discuss this issue? Why does antiquoting the `nil` part fix things?

This question is similar to, but not the same as, [Proper reinitialization of a list? What is happening under the hood?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18444/proper-reinitialization-of-a-list-what-is-happening-under-the-hood). The answers to that question doesn't discuss why using `nil` isn't a problem, nor do they explain why antiquoting nil makes a difference. Additionally, I am looking for references in the Emacs lisp manual.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper reinitialization of a list? What is happening under the hood?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18444/proper-reinitialization-of-a-list-what-is-happening-under-the-hood)

Comment: I tried to clarify the differences. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/16670989/729907

Comment: In elisp, `(backquote (form))` behaves the same as `(quote (form))` when there are no evaluated or spliced components. Therefore see http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/20535 and also related Q&As http://stackoverflow.com/q/36964728 (for hash tables) and http://stackoverflow.com/q/18790192 (not elisp specific).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the Constant in \`let\` Designed in This way?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20535/why-the-constant-in-let-designed-in-this-way)

Comment: Your first block manipulates the same Lisp object, check this with `(eq a b)` before and after the `push`, whereas `,nil` creates different objects. IMO the duplicate answer explains that pretty well.

Comment: For backquote, see the Elisp manual, node [Backquote](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html). There you will see that it can quote only part of a sexp, evaluating other parts (preceded by commas).  Your second backquoted sexp macroexpands to `(list (list 'x))`, and `list` creates new list structure when invoked.

Comment: If you want to see what's going on (mostly - except details of the Lisp reader), use `macroexpand` on each of the sexps you are interested in -- e.g., `(push 1 (alist-get 'x a))`

Comment: @Drew the stackoverflow question is indeed it. Is there a way to mark cross-site duplicates?

Comment: @Clément: As far as I know, no - there is apparently no problem with duplicates across sites. Cross-referencing the duplicate or similar post on another site can be helpful, at least.

Answer (score 2):

This does require precision to state correctly; I'll give it a go.

Whenever a form is read in, `read` is creating some lisp structure as it goes. The result of reading the text "(defun my-new-alist () `((x . nil)))" is a list of four elements, `'defun`, `'my-new-alist`, `nil`, and finally `(quote ((x . nil)))`. When you `eval` this list, `eval` creates a function object using the `caaar` and `caaaar` as the argument list and the body, and assigns it to the environment using the name in the `caar`. This is straight forward.

Now when you call the function, it has to `eval` the body in the environment created by extending the environment of the call site by creating new bindings for the formal paramters in the arglist and the values from the call (this is just dynamic scope, and isn't actually relevant here, since your arglist is nil). The first thing it evaluates here is the call to the `quote` special form. `quote` is a form and not a function, because it specifically returns its argument without evaluating it, whereas all the arguments to a function call are evaluated automatically. Thus all calls to `my-new-alist` return a reference to the same list, in fact to the list that was created when this form was `read`.

Now we look at `push`. If we look in the ELisp manual, on the List Variables page (run `M-x (info "(elisp)List Variables")` to jump right to it), we see that "[push] creates a new list whose CAR is ELEMENT and whose CDR is the list specified by LISTNAME, and saves that list in LISTNAME." We also see that `push` is equivalent to `(setf LISTNAME (cons ELEMENT LISTNAME))`. In this case, that's `(setf (alist-get 'x a) (cons 1 (alist-get 'x a))`. This actually changes the value of the `cdr` in your alist to point to the newly-created `cons`. Anyone who has a reference to the alist will then see this new `cons`.

Comment: You should explain that the backquote is a macro which expands into `quote` after reading but before evaluating `defun` (actually `defun` is macro too, but you can ignore that aspect here).

Comment: For this particular topic, I think it's important to differentiate the *lisp objects* resulting from the read phase, and the textual code which was read (and/or the printed representation of the objects). When you use (only) textual lisp code to represent the objects which will be evaluated, I don't think it's obvious why that isn't the same thing as the original text code processed by the reader. Making the distinction clarifies why certain things are *the same object* while others are not.

Comment: @phils: yes, it really ought to have some box-and-pointer diagrams